# Efficient CSV Reading package in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a very large csv file (~56000x18000), and am looking for a package to read it quickly. In R, the data.table package has fread which is written in C and can do it in less than a minute. I tried read_csv in pandas, but even when explicitly specificying it use the C engine it takes at least 10 minutes. Is there some equivalent in Python that is more efficient/faster?

Comment: considere to use like an option pyspark

Comment: I'm not sure this is a programming question. There are [duplicates](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79449/need-fast-csv-parser-for-python-to-parse-80gb-csv-file) (or at least related questions) on [several](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-free-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file-with-13-columns-of-numbers) other [sites](https://superuser.com/questions/775893/whats-the-quickest-way-to-parse-and-display-a-csv-file) in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options:

1. You can look into using the `chunksize` parameter in `pandas.read_csv` instead of loading the whole file into memory at once:

```py
import pandas as pd

chunks = pd.read_csv(input_file, chunksize=10000)
df = pd.concat(chunks)
```

2. Similar to R, you can use the `data.table` package for Python:

```py
import datatable as dt

data = dt.fread(input_file)
```

3. You can use dask:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv(“random.csv”)
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using chuncks: `df = pd.concat(chunks)`

Comment: The datatable and dask packages both worked great. Thank you!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you mean it's an issue if there is a memory issue with holding the entire df in memory post-processing? The chunks here would still address the potential problem of loading and processing the entire csv at once.